# наиболее часто встречающийся элемент в массиве

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
-- таблица постов
CREATE TABLE sports_posts (
  post_id int, tags int[]
);

INSERT INTO sports_posts (post_id, tags) VALUES 
(1, '{1, 2, 3}'), (2, '{3, 2, 4, 5, 7}'),
(3, '{6}'), (4, '{1, 7}'),
(5, '{4, 5, 3}'), (6, '{1, 4, 5}'),
(7, '{5, 6, 7}'), (8, '{7, 8}'),
(9, '{4}'), (0, '{3, 7, 8}');


-- таблица тегов
CREATE TABLE sports_tags (
  tag_id int, name varchar
);

INSERT INTO sports_tags (tag_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'ЦСКА'), (2, 'Зенит'), (3, 'Спартак'),
(4, 'МЮ'), (5, 'Барселона'), (6, 'Реал'),
(7, 'Челси'), (8, 'Милан');
```

найти топ 5 тегов, наиболее часто встречающихся в постах.

Comment: С чем помочь? В чём у вас возникла проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
select tag, 
       count(1) as cnt -- посчитаем сколько раз встречается каждый тег
from   (select unnest(tags) as tag  -- развернем массивы в строки
        from   sports_posts as t ) as t2
group  by tag  
order  by 2 desc
limit  5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d7f8/18

Comment: Немного поправил, что-бы выводились именно названия тегов, а не их id. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7d7f8/23